# mysql bulk records update?

Tags: php, mysql

This code won't work, how can I fix:

```
<?php $response = $amazonEcs->responsegroup('Large')->lookup('echo $row_Recordset1['ASIN'];');
$title = ($response['Items']['Item']['ItemAttributes']['Title']); print_r($title);?>
```

Note that if i were to have  somewhere else it would correctly connect to the database and call the ASIN from the table and the entire code would work if instead of calling from a table I wrote a static ASIN. So the problem is most likely:

```
lookup('echo $row_Recordset1['ASIN'];');
```

Comment: At least tell us which library u use, although I can have a good guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check bellow code.

```
<?php 
$response = $amazonEcs->responsegroup('Large')->lookup($row_Recordset1['ASIN']);
$title = $response['Items']['Item']['ItemAttributes']['Title']; 
?>
```

And your lookup function call should be like this.

```
lookup($row_Recordset1['ASIN']);
```

Answer (score 0):

The lookup reference won't work in PHP. This is what you need:

```
lookup($row_Recordset1['ASIN']);
```

No need for the echo statement since you're already in a PHP block and just need the value of that column passed to the lookup function.

Answer (score 0):

you are calling some lookup function in php , so you can remove echo and single quotes from it

```
lookup($row_Recordset1["ASIN"])
```

will work